# Why does pip freeze list "pkg-resources==0.0.0"?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04

On Ubuntu 16.04 with virtualenv 15.0.1 and Python 3.5.2 (both installed with `apt`) when I create and activate new Python virtual environment with

```sh
virtualenv .virtualenvs/wtf -p $(which python3) --no-site-packages
source .virtualenvs/wtf/bin/activate
```

I get the following output:

```
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/das-g/.virtualenvs/wtf/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/das-g/.virtualenvs/wtf/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
```

Indeed `pip freeze --all` lists these 4 packages:

```
pip==8.1.2
pkg-resources==0.0.0
setuptools==25.2.0
wheel==0.29.0
```

Though, I'd expect `pip freeze` (without `--all`) to omit these implicitly installed packages. It does omit some of them, but not `pkg-resources`:

```
pkg-resources==0.0.0
```

(Same btw. for `pip freeze --local`)

While this is consistent with the help text

```sh
$> pip freeze --help | grep '\--all'
  --all                       Do not skip these packages in the output: pip, setuptools, distribute, wheel
```

having `pkg-resources` in the `pip freeze` output doesn't seem very useful and might even be harmful. (I suspect it's why running `pip-sync` from [pip-tools](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools) uninstalls pkg-resources from the virtual environment, subtly breaking the environment thereby.) **Is there any good reason why `pip freeze` lists `pkg-resources` instead of omitting it, too?** As far as I remember, it didn't list it on Ubuntu 14.04 (with Python 3.4).

Comment: I don't know why exactly this happens. This happened to me with a different package that was actually essential for my project. The solution I found was to edit the requirements.txt with the latest available version on PyPi. One possibility, I'm guessing, is the version that was initially installed is no longer available on PyPi.

Comment: It's amazing that there isn't an answer for this yet...

Comment: This caused a production push to fail for me, so I am very curious as to the answer / resolution.

Comment: I created a ticket, it may eventually provide an answer: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4022

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1635463

Comment: Debian bug report [#871790](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=871790) is also about this issue.

Comment: I recently this issue although both Ubuntu and pip have been fixed. I don't know why. I fixed it by removing the virtual environment and making a new one. You can find steps on how to do that online

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4022, this is a bug resulting from Ubuntu providing incorrect metadata to pip. So, no there does not seem to be a good reason for this behaviour. I filed a follow-up bug with Ubuntu. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1635463

Comment: This affects Debian users too. Looks like the fix was made for Ubuntu [see the most recent comment of original bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1635463) and Debian ([#1](https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/modules/python-pip/-/commit/5ccaf859a5b168e65368b61aa47fec53f32a367c) [#2](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=871790)).

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem in my virtual environment. I removed it with `pip uninstall pkg-resources==0.0.0`

Comment: Warning: This may subtly break your virtualenv.

Comment: @das-g In what way it may break virtualenv?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite remember what the issue was back then, and I don't have an Ubuntu system handy at the moment. IIRC, `pkg-resources` is an integral part of the virtualenv and needed by Python, pip or maybe virtualenv itself. Not sure what exactly would stop working when it's missing.