# What is "pkg-resources==0.0.0" in output of pip freeze command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-16.04

When I run `pip freeze` I see (among other expected packages) `pkg-resources==0.0.0`. I have seen a few posts mentioning this package (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992194/why-does-pip-freeze-list-pkg-resources-0-0-0)), but none explaining what it is, or why it is included in the output of `pip freeze`. The main reason I am wondering is out of curiosity, but also, it seems to break things in some cases when trying to install packages with a `requirements.txt` file generated with `pip freeze` that includes the `pkg-resources==0.0.0` line (for example when [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) tries to install dependencies through `pip` and finds this line).

**What is `pkg-resources`, and is it OK to remove this line from `requirements.txt`?**

## Update:

I have found that this line only seems to exist in the output of `pip freeze` when I am in a `virtualenv`. I am still not sure what it is or what it does, but I will investigate further knowing that it is likely related to `virtualenv`.

Comment: *"it seems to break things in some cases when trying to install packages with a requirements.txt file generated with pip freeze that includes the pkg-resources==0.0.0 line."*. Can you maybe give an example for that?

Comment: @Jim, good point. I added the example that I ran into.

Comment: hm, what's your version of `pip`? I'm thinking this might of been something they missed in an old release since in `8.1.2` I have no entry for `pkg-resources`. (Which it shouldn't since I'm pretty sure `pkg-resources` comes with `setuptools`).

Comment: @Jim My `pip` version is `8.1.2`.

Comment: Well, this is odd. I too am on `Ubuntu 16.04` with `pip 8.1.2` and *still* don't see it.

Comment: @Jim it just occurred to me that it may be related to `virtualenv`, and indeed, when I am *not* in a virtualenv I don't see it either. This still does not explain what it is, but at least is a clue that I can investigate.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992194/why-does-pip-freeze-list-pkg-resources-0-0-0/40167000?noredirect=1#comment67602638_40167000 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does pip freeze list "pkg-resources==0.0.0"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992194/why-does-pip-freeze-list-pkg-resources-0-0-0)

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate of @CraigWright's ticket SO post. See [my comment on his post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992194/why-does-pip-freeze-list-pkg-resources-0-0-0#comment108357289_40167000). They've fixed this for both Debian and Ubuntu installs.

Comment: still not fixed with ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 257, accepted):

According to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4022, this is a bug resulting from Ubuntu providing incorrect metadata to pip. So, no there does not seem to be a good reason for this behaviour. I filed a follow-up bug with Ubuntu. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1635463

To backup the previous answer, it should be safe to remove that line from your requirements.txt. Here is an example Make file stanza that safely freezes your package list (drop in your Makefile and run with `make freeze`):

```
freeze:
    pip freeze | grep -v "pkg-resources" > requirements.txt
```

*edit 2022 July 06:*

I have been informed that the package name differs depending on the system in use (`pkg-resources` vs `pkg_resources`). Please see the comments attached to this answer for differences in usage between different versions of Debian/Ubuntu. As `pkg-resources` is the historically correct package name at the time this was posted (almost 6 years ago) for the system in question, it will remain unchanged in this answer.

Comment: It's not Ubuntu-specific bug, debian has same issue

Comment: At first @MohammedShareefC idea seemed to work, but then I got `AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'iter_entry_points'`, so I thinks its best just to remove it from `requirements.txt`

Comment: still causing headache when trying to deploy to heroku

Comment: This seems still an issue with ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Still an issue with Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: Still an issue with venv of Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @Pynchia i too.

Comment: For Python3 in Ubuntu 20.04 (venv) `pip freeze | grep "pkg_resources" > requirements.txt` instead "pkg-resources"

Answer (score 19):

As for the part of your question "**is it OK to remove this line?**":

I have the same issue here developing on an ubuntu 16.04 with that very line in the requirements. When deploying on a debian 8.5 running `"pip install -r requirements.txt"` pip complains that pkg-resources  is "not found" but there is a global package installed "python-pkg-resources" so the dependency should be satisfied. Same on ubuntu: The package exists there as well.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992194/why-does-pip-freeze-list-pkg-resources-0-0-0) it seems to be some "implicitly installed package".

So: **If you are on a Debian/Ubuntu having python-pkg-resources installed it should be safe to remove that line**. I did so and everything is running fine. However since I am no expert on this you should keep in mind that this might lead to complications when deploying on another machine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up removing it too and have not seen any consequences either, but the same caveats you mention apply of course. Where you installing to/from a `virtualenv` as well?

Comment: Yes, I tried installing from inside a virtualenv. Since systemwide package is present and I did not want to mess things up I did not try installing per pip systemwide.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in this link: [pip freeze includes "pkg-resources==0.0.0"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1635463) in comment 10 by: Louis Bouchard (louis) posted: 2019-11-16:

It worked for me. But I'm not an expert so, if someone undestands it better, would be great if explained it.

For what it's worth, the problem comes from the debianized version of virtualenv which uses a debundled version of `pkg_resource` which gets added into the virtualenv at creation time:

```
$ virtualenv .
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /home/caribou/git/quividi/test/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /home/caribou/git/quividi/test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
$ pip freeze
pkg-resources==0.0.0
```

Using the pip installed version of virtualenv can be a viable workaround :

```
$ sudo apt -y purge python3-virtualenv virtualenv tox
$ pip install virtualenv
$ virtualenv .
pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/97/00dd42a0fc41e9016b23f07ec7f657f636cb672fad9cf72b80f8f65c6a46/virtualenv-16.7.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.4MB 351kB/s
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv-16.7.7
$ virtualenv .
New python executable in /home/caribou/git/quividi/test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
$ source bin/activate
$ pip freeze
$
```