# Deploying a Django Application to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

I am new to Django and I am trying to deploy a Django App on AWS following the tutorial on AWS [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html).
Everything works fine until I execute the command `eb create django-env`. The deploy exits with an error message: *Invalid requirements.txt*.
In the log file I have the following:

```
Collecting Django==1.9.12 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
Downloading Django-1.9.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6MB)
Collecting pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
```

I am sorry if the issue may be trivial,

but can anyone point to the right direction?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167445/3926995)

Comment: Thanks Chiheb, that really helped !!!