# Your Requirement.txt is invalid : returned non zero exit status1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, requirements.txt

I am trying to deploy django app on AWS elastic Beanstalk. on local machine i made a virtual environment and got all required libraries in requirements.tx using freeze command. 
After creating app as per the tutorial on aws i used eb create app_name-env -s (-s for single instance) I am getting following error [image: Here is the complete screenshot of terminal]

you can see eb-activity-log file  here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PMX9ep6ZDZPk2jN-Fdbl3LyjLmMTAkhE/view?usp=sharing

also requirement.txt here  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KnxP_v0DQcA4QezXKO_6-CBbgpAlEnvD/view?usp=sharing

Note- i am using python3.6 on local machine as well as creating eb app using python3.6.

What is the cause for this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 7)`

Comment: what is the pkg-resources? is it performing any key role here ? i just installed django and social-auth plugin for django , not sure what is this pkg-resource?

Comment: Short story, it's a bug, manually remove it from your txt file. Long story here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577984/what-is-pkg-resources-0-0-0-in-output-of-pip-freeze-command