# No matching distribution found for package have "ubuntu" in there name

Tags: python, linux, docker, pip

I am have some problem while install pip package in docker image.

My Dockerfile is like this

```
....
RUN python -m venv /vir_env
RUN . /vir_env/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
....
```

My requirements.txt file is generate by `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

But when I run docker build it always error in package have "ubuntu" in there name `python-apt==2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.6`, `distro-info===0.23ubuntu1`

Error log:

```sh
....
#13 5.890 ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-apt==2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.6
#13 6.360 WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
#13 6.360 You should consider upgrading via the '/vir_env/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
error: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c . /vir_env/bin/activate && pip3 install -r /requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

```sh
....
#13 5.890 ERROR: No matching distribution found for distro-info===0.23ubuntu1
#13 6.360 WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
#13 6.360 You should consider upgrading via the '/vir_env/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
error: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c . /vir_env/bin/activate && pip3 install -r /requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

I already try pip upgrade but not don't work.

Is there any other way to fix or is there any update about this but I missed ?

Comment: You might be using a non-Ubuntu container (e.g. Debian). Check the `FROM` line in your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @mkayaalp `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:20.04` this is my image container

Comment: [What is "pkg-resources==0.0.0" in output of pip freeze command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577984/what-is-pkg-resources-0-0-0-in-output-of-pip-freeze-command) suggests this is a bug in the Ubuntu-packaged `virtualenv` tool.  You might try re-running `pip freeze` on the host, maybe using `python3 -m venv` to create a new virtual environment first.

Comment: @DavidMaze I just re-running `pip freeze` in docker so it not have any package name with `ubuntu`

Comment: sometimes is because the package doesn't exist for the version of ubuntu you are using. try upgrading or downgrading your ubuntu base

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what problem is it.

But I make new ubuntu container and install package manually and try `pip freeze > requirements.txt` it don't generate any pip package with "ubuntu" in there name.

I think there is some problem with my docker or my pip package.