# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

My app is deployed on `heroku`.

When I push my code via `git push heroku master`. It gives me this error

```
Collecting pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14)) (from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

`requirement.txt`

```
amqp==2.1.1
billiard==3.5.0.2
boto==2.42.0
celery==4.0.0
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.10.2
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-model-utils==2.6
django-storages==1.5.1
djangorestframework==3.4.7
gunicorn==19.6.0
Jinja2==2.8
kombu==4.0.0
MarkupSafe==0.23
optional-django==0.1.0
pep8==1.7.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
pyflakes==1.3.0
pytz==2016.7
rcssmin==1.0.6
requests==2.12.1
rjsmin==1.0.12
vine==1.1.3
whitenoise==3.2.2
```

**Note**: Its working perfectly fine on my local server.

My Question is why is not working on `heroku` but working on `local`. ???

Comment: please comment the 14 line in requirement.txt and push the code

Comment: I get that.  But why its working on local and not on heroku

Comment: it that working properly without that module

Comment: Yes it was working, But i wanted to ask why its not working on heroku

Comment: i dont know may me heroku cammot find that module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does pip freeze list "pkg-resources==0.0.0"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992194/why-does-pip-freeze-list-pkg-resources-0-0-0)

Comment: I get that its not a direct duplicate but I'd imagine its because your local version already has it installed and therefore doesn't need to go looking for it

Comment: can you show pip freeze output on your local env?

Comment: The [SO post mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670602/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-pkg-resources-0-0-0#comment68573207_40670602) speaks to the heart of the issue. I don't know anything about Heroku, but from what I can tell, it uses an OS called _Stack_ which is [built on top of Ubuntu](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack). I'm wondering if Adil wasn't running a Ubuntu/Debian distro locally, and so his issues only appeared when pushing his code up to Heroku.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Remove Following line from *requirements.txt*.

`pkg-resources==0.0.0`

Answer (score 32):

To avoid having it in requirements.txt everytime you do a freeze, remove it from your virtual environment with `pip uninstall pkg-resources==0.0.0`

Comment: What is it, why does it appear in the first place?

Answer (score 6):

Remove `pkg-resources==0.0.0` from requirements.txt

if you wish to avoid the problem next time you do a freeze, use `pip uninstall pkg-resources==0.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

`cat requirements.txt | grep --invert-match pkg-resources | xargs -n 1 pip install`

refer to the link for a more detailed write-up:
https://code-specialist.com/python/pkg-resources

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It appears Heroku CLI is using dependencies from a different local branch.
If you are running:

```
$ git push origin master
```

to deploy your application on Heroku, ensure that locally you are switched to master branch.